# How to show and hide a StackLayout based on ListView scroll direction in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a screen with a `ListView` that shows a collection of comments. Also, I have a `StackLayout` overlapping the end of the `ListView`, which has an `Entry` and a `Button` to add a new comment.

I want to hide/show this `StackLayout` depending on the `ListView` scrolling direction:

- If the user scrolls down -> hide the `StackLayout`.
- If the user scrolls up -> show the `StackLayout`.

Anyone knows a way to accomplish that behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could add a SwipeGestureRecognizer to the ListView's GestureRecognizers collection. Specify direction on the recognizer, and handle the recognizer's Swiped event. I am not sure if this will interfere with the ListView's scrolling behavior, though.

Comment: Have you tried Flutter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xamarin.Forms `ListView` provides an `OnItemAppearing` event you can subscribe to. With this you can track your scroll direction by finding the index of the item that appeared and comparing it to the last item that appeared. Try something like this:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyItemType> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyItemType>();
    int lastItemIndex;
    int currentItemIndex;

    public MainPage()
    {
        ...
        listView.ItemAppearing += ListView_ItemAppearing;
    }

    void ListView_ItemAppearing(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
    {
        MyItemType item = e.Item as MyItemType;

        currentItemIndex = Items.IndexOf(item);
        if (currentItemIndex > lastItemIndex)
        {
            stackLayout.IsVisible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            stackLayout.IsVisible = true;
        }
        lastItemIndex = currentItemIndex;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Flickering is really due to `ListView` being resized when the `StackLayout` shows and hides, so make sure that the `ListView` is not getting resized. Perhaps put the ListView and the StackLayout in a grid so that when you show and hide the `StackLayout` the `ListView` does not get resized, e.g.:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="35" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="listView"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
              Grid.Row="0">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            ...
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <StackLayout x:Name="stackLayout"
                 Grid.Row="1">
        ...
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

With the above, the flickering no longer occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have tried something like this, but when I scroll up, the `StackLayout` is displayed and hidden repeatedly and very quickly, generating strange behavior for the user.
I wrote console messages in `if` and `else`, and I realized that when I scroll up, the `ItemAppearing` event is triggered to elements that are already on the screen.
I don't know how to avoid that behavior.

Comment: Might be best for you to post the code you are using to see if we can spot why. I did not experience that issue when I tested the above.

Comment: Ah, Actually I can reproduce the issue, but it only occurs when scrolling very slowly. Scrolling down very slowly, I may see the same item twice in a row, but scrolling up is where I see something more incorrect. The method is getting called both for the item appearing AND the item disappearing off the bottom of the screen (tested on iOS). Same happens on Android and is more pronounced where the method is called for every item in the list view. I will get a bug filed and report back.

Comment: That's exactly what I was talking about! Thanks.

Comment: Found a workaround that hopefully will work for you. Editing my answer.

Comment: Great job. I'll test it tomorrow at work, first thing in the morning.

Comment: I think I see the issue. It is because the ListView is resized when the stacklayout is hidden,i.e. the ListView gets one element longer, and on iOS this just causes one more item to appear, but on android the whole list view seems to be re-rendered so all of the cells are indeed appearing again. So not a bug, but you just need to set your layout so the ListView won't resize when you show and hide the stacklayout. Maybe use a grid to hold the ListView and the StackLayout so hiding the layout won't change ListView size.

Comment: Just tested, and I am correct. Not a bug, just make sure that the listView does not get resized. Updating answer.

Comment: I understand and yes, in my case the ListView is resized when the StackLayout appears.